# How can I pass value(contents) of HTML textbox to a javascript function on a button click?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a java script function

```
function findInthePage(str)
{
// code
}
```

How can I pass the contents of a HTML text box to the above function?
My button click code is

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" name="tb1" />
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="findInthePage(text1.value);" />
```

Comment: Safer (and easier) to get the value from inside the function since you dont need to worry about presence of quotes etc. in the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var text = document.getElementById('Text1').value
```

Answer (score 2):

The value property is used with Form elements, it gets or sets values to fields of the form.

- To use "getElementById('id')" with form elements, they must have assigned an "id".
  Here's a simple example that displays an Alert with the text written in a text box.

  function test7() {
  var val7 = document.getElementById("ex7").value;
  alert(val7);
  }
  html

  // input type="text" id="ex7"

  // input type="button" value="Click" onclick="test7()"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("Text1");
findInthePage(textBox.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onClick="findInthePage(document.getElementById('Text1').value)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access input directly from the function like:

```
function findInthePage()
{
// code

var input = document.getElementById('Button1').value;


}
```

If you want your way:

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" name="tb1" />
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="findInthePage(document.getElementById('Button1').value);" />
```

Comment: He wants the text of the text input, not the button.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var value = null;
document.getElementById("Button1").onclick = function(){
    value = document.getElementById("Text1").value;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="txtbox" type="text" name="tb1" />
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="clickme();"/>

script
function clickme() {
    var aa = document.getElementById("txtbox").value;
    alert(aa);

}
```